# Next.js 13 can't deploy on AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify

I have next.js 13 repo on AWS CodeCommit, then I try to deploy on AWS Amplify but I got error like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nboPd.png)

"Houston, there's a problem
We are unable to process your request. Please reach out to your support representative."

anyone has solution to solve this error?

thank you.

Comment: Sounds like an internal error. I would retry then raise a support ticket.